# Swap 2 select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I have 2 dropdowns on my site(One is 'From dropdown' and another is 'To dropdown'). There is a button in between them.

I want to swap the positions of these dropdown when users clicks the button. Like 'From' becomes 'To' and 'To' becomes 'From' without losing the selected value. And also there id and name should be updated properly for form submission.

This is my code structure right now --

```
<fieldset class="select">
    <label><?php __('From'); ?></label>
    <?php
    echo $form->select(
        'from',
        $languages,
        $selectedLanguageFrom,
        array(
            'class' => 'language-selector',
            "empty" => false
        ),
        false
    );
    ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="into">
    <span id="into">&raquo;</span>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="select">
    <label><?php __('To'); ?></label>
    <?php
    echo $form->select(
        'to',
        $languages,
        $selectedLanguageTo,
        array(
            'class' => 'language-selector',
            "empty" => false
        ),
        false
    );
    ?>
</fieldset>
```

I tried doing this --

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#arrow" ).click(function() {
        var obj1=$("#fieldset2").prev();
        var obj2=$("#fieldset2").next();
        $("#fieldset2").before(obj2);
        $("#fieldset2").after(obj1);
    });
})
```

But I think this not a best way to do this. What would be the best way to implement this. Examples with JSFiddle would be helpful.

Edit - 
Selected option should not swap. Only the label,id and name should swap.
HTML Code of the output --

```
<fieldset class="select">
    <label>From</label>
    <select name="from" class="language-selector" id="SentenceFrom">
<option value="und" selected="selected">Any</option>
<option value="abk">Abkhaz</option>
<option value="afr">Afrikaans</option>
<option value="ain">Ainu</option>
</select></fieldset>

<fieldset class="into">
    <span id="into">&raquo;</span>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="select">
    <label>To</label>
    <select name="to" class="language-selector" id="SentenceTo">
<option value="und" selected="selected">Any</option>
<option value="abk">Abkhaz</option>
<option value="afr">Afrikaans</option>
<option value="ain">Ainu</option>
</select></fieldset>
```

Comment: What is the intent here? Are you actually trying to switch the *values* so that the 'To' dropdown has the value of 'From' and vice versa on the button press, or are you literally just switching the positions of the two elements on the page (a purely visual change)?

Comment: why did you change dropdownlist's position ,its better to swap contents,its look like the dropdown are swapped

Comment: Basically I am trying to swap 'From' and 'To' positions and also id & name of both dropdowns should also updated accordingly for form submission. The selected values in dropdown should remain there.

Comment: Add HTML of what you see in Browser/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var clicks = 0;
$( "#arrow" ).click(function() {
    var obj1=$("#fieldset1");
    var obj2=$("#fieldset2");
    $("#fieldset1").remove();
    $("#fieldset2").remove();

    if ( clicks%2 == 0){            

        $(".into").before(obj2);
        $(".into").after(obj1);
    }else{            

        $(".into").before(obj1);
        $(".into").after(obj2);
    }
    clicks++;
});
})
```

You can check the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/L6bworxw/)

**EDIT:** If that is the case then this is your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#arrow" ).click(function() {
    var obj1=$("#fieldset1");
    var obj2=$("#fieldset2");
    var label1=$("#fieldset1 > label");
    var label2=$("#fieldset2 > label");
    var id1=$("#fieldset1 select").attr("id");
    var id2=$("#fieldset2 select").attr("id");
    var name1=$("#fieldset1 select").attr("name");
    var name2=$("#fieldset2 select").attr("name");
    label1.remove();
    label2.remove();

    obj1.prepend(label2);
    obj2.prepend(label1);
    $("#fieldset1 select").attr("id",id2);
    $("#fieldset2 select").attr("id",id1);
    $("#fieldset1 select").attr("name",name2);
    $("#fieldset2 select").attr("name",name1);

});
})
```

And you can wath it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/L6bworxw/8/)

Comment: This is the same thing that I was doing.Selected option should not swap. Only the to and from labels should swap and the respected id and name should be updated.

Comment: Thank You this is what I wanted to achieve